# Azure Application insight request response stat vs the actual page response time on client side

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights

My QA team is complaining it takes 4 seconds to see the result comes up when they test a search function in our application.

Our application is hosted on an on-premise IIS server where I install the Azure Application Insight agent to collect data to send it to the Azure portal.

I am using the Application Insight performance feature to see the total response of a POST transaction which shows only 1 second for this POST search request to execute.

[image]

When I search for all request in this time slot, I only see this POST and no other request such as GET.  I conclude this search does not need to refresh the page and instead just display the result as a post back.

Is it indicative for me to conclude that this search in total should only be 1 seconds and not 4 seconds as per my QA team finding?

If the above is not showing the entire picture, do you know if Azure application insight has any logging that shows the total time? I don't know if Azure Application Insight has a way to see the total time client browser takes to load the result or if there maybe a client proxy involved?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upon further investigation I conclude what Application Insight only shows is the request in the server side.

What I did was running the search on the browser with F12 enabled to see the total request time.  It turns out the time to fully load the page with result is much more than the total request time that Application Insight post on the request transaction.

Comment: Yep, you'd need to use AI JS SDK in-browser to get Page View load times and backend queries turnaround. AI .NET SDK works in the app itself and can only detect time from the moment app received request to the moment the app replied back - no network, no server queue would be included.